# Wireless LAN but no internet

Tags: 14.04, networking, router

I have a Ubuntu machine (U) connected by wire to a wireless router, and a robot machine (R) connected wirelessly to the same router.

(U) is online and can ssh into (R) without problem. However, (U) can ping (R) but not '8.8.8.8', not 'google.com'.

What could be the reason behind?

Comment: "(U) is online" - what? Looks like the router isn't connected to anything, or (U) doesn't have a default route.

Comment: Yea, (U) is definitely online, and the router admin page says the router is connected to Internet also.

Comment: what's your default gateway? Can you ping it? How are you getting your IP? DHCP or static?  edit your post and add output from `netstat -rn` from (U)